# How to implement conditional nested properties with JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I have base json schema `base.schema.json`

```
{
  "$id": "base.schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "remote_os": {
      "default": "Windows",
      "enum": [
        "Linux",
        "Windows" ]
     }
  },
  "required": ["remote_os"]
}
```

Now referenced the schema definition in another json

```
{
  "$id": "update.schema.json",
  "properties": {
    "common_data": {
      "$ref": "base.schema.json"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "common_data": {
            "remote_os": {
              "const": "Windows"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "file": {
            "pattern": "^(.*.)(exe)$"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "common_data": {
            "remote_os": {
              "const": "Linux",
              "required": [
                "remote_os"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "file": {
            "pattern": "^(.*.)(bin)$"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically adding the `if-else` logic to make sure for `remote_os=Linux` `file` should ended up with `.bin` and `remote_os=Windows` `file` should ended up with `.exe`
Now I am trying to validate against below data

```
{
  "common_data": {
    "remote_os": "Linux"
  },
  "file": "abc.bin"
}
```

`[<ValidationError: "'abc.bin' does not match '^(.*.)(exe)$'">]`. Not sure what's wrong here

Comment: What's hard to understand with *"'abc.bin' does not match '^(.\*.)(exe)$'"*?

Comment: For validation data `remote_os` = `Linux` and as per `if-else` in JSON Schema `update.schema.json` `file` should ended up with `bin` extension. So my validation data was correct only, it shouldn't raise the `ValidationError`

Comment: Ah, I see. I suggest a better question title: *"How to check nested properties with JSON Schema if else"* instead of "not working".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have changed the title now.

Comment: In the example the reference schema definition is part of same JSON, I hope it will also work for local file reference also. Still didn't get where the `if-else` should go.Some example will really help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating it - surly just if/then/else?

```
{
  "if": {
    "properties": { "common_data": "properties": { "remote_os": { "const": "Windows" } } }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": { "file": { "pattern": "^(.*.)(exe)$" } }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": { "file": { "pattern": "^(.*.)(bin)$" } }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that actually , but its not working. Its always looking for `"pattern": "^(.*.)(exe)$"` pattern , irrespective of `remote_os` is `Windows or Linux`

Comment: You have an error in your schema (both the question and the answer): you are missing an extra `"properties: { ... ` betwheen "common_data" and "remote_os". Schemas that have no recognized keywords are always true, which is why the "then" path is always evaluating.